# drop down selections not remaining selected after form submission

Tags: php, html

I am trying to clean up a search mysql webform so that all the functions (and there are many) reside in external files, called with `require(fileName.php);` in the form page, wanting to make the main webform.php a lot easier to follow and manage.

I have quite a few drop down menus in a searchDb.php form page for the user to select search criteria from, which are all scripted similar to:

```
    <p> <!-- Technician: -->
    <label for"Technician:">Technician:</label>
      <select name="searchTech" id="searchTech">
        <option value="0">-- Select Technician --</option>
          <?php
            techDDM($searchTech, isset($_POST['submitted']))
          ?>
      </select>
```

When the form first loads the drop down menus are populated as expected, and in this example by the function call `techDDM()` that resides in: `require('dropDownMenu.php');`

```
function techDDM(&$searchTech, $sbmtd) {
  // initialize and populate techArr
  $techArr = array('First Last1', 'First Last2', 'First Last3', 'First Last4', 'First Last5', 'First Last6', 'First Last7', 'First Last8', 'First Last9');

  echo  '<br />(' . __LINE__ . ') $searchTech : ' . $searchTech . '<br />'; // output for debug
  echo  '<br />(' . __LINE__ . ') $sbmtd : ' . $sbmtd . '<br />'; // output for debug
  foreach ($techArr as $t) {
    echo "<option value='$t'";
    if ($sbmtd == 1 && $searchTech == '$t') {
      echo " selected";
    }
    echo ">$t</option>";
  }
}
```

But after the form is submitted and if it is determined one of the text fields in which the user typed input contains errors, and if the user additionally selected a name from the `Select Technician` drop down menu, for example, as additional search criteria, then the I intend for the user's drop down selections to remain selected while they are prompted to fix typed errors. Unfortunately, the `selected` attribute for the option value the user selected is not being included in the `<option` tag, yet the condition is being met to include the selected attribute as shown in the page's source for the Technician section rendered by the HTML and PHP examples pasted above:

```
<p> <!-- Technician: -->
        <label for"Technician:">Technician:</label>
          <select name="searchTech" id="searchTech">
            <option value="0">-- Select Technician --</option>
              <br />(8) $searchTech : First Last1<br /><br />(9) $sbmtd : 1<br /><option value='First Last1'>First Last1</option><option value='First Last2'>First Last2</option><option value='First Last3'>First Last3</option><option value='First Last4'>First Last4</option><option value='First Last5'>First Last5</option><option value='First Last6'>First Last6</option><option value='First Last7'>First Last7</option><option value='First Last8'>First Last8</option><option value='First Last9'>First Last9</option>          </select>
        <span id="spanSpace"></span>
```

The source shows that tech selection: `First Last1` was indeed selected, and the page was also submitted: `$sbmtd == 1`, which should then append the `selected` attribute to `First Last1, but that is just not happening.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or leaving out trying to get this working?

Comment: You are comparing your $searchTech variable with the _literal_ text `$t`.

Comment: Varaibles in single quotes `'$t'` are not parsed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: @Cbroe & u_mulder thanks for the point in the right direction. As soon as I read your comments and made the necessary change, all became good once more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your condition:

```
if ($sbmtd == 1 && $searchTech == $t) {
      echo " selected";
    }
```